# Extra instance of CLLocationManager?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on a project where I create 2 instances of CLLocationManager, my question is that when I look in instrument whilst my code is running is shows 3 instances, is this right, what is creating the 3rd one, or is it just a system thing?

**XCODE:**

[image]

**INSTRUMENTS:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the middle one is being created by your MKMapView (I assume you are using one). MKMapView has a location manager behind it, it's how it can carry out the `showUserLocation` feature. `MKLocationManager` is not a public class, and the map view won't expose it to you so there's not much you can really do about it.

Comment: Hi lxt, much appreciated, yes I am using a MKMapView, I am fine with the extra instance being there now I know what it is, I just wanted to know where it came from.